# Android Background service stop when mobile screen lock after few minute

Tags: android, mobile, android-service, background-service

I have to tried to implement online streaming radio application, but it is stop when screen lock after few minute please help me to fix this problem.

my mobile phone os is android 9

```
public class AudioService extends Service {


    private AudioServiceBinder audioServiceBinder = new AudioServiceBinder();

    public AudioService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return audioServiceBinder;
    }


}
```

```
public class AudioServiceBinder extends Binder {

    // Save local audio file uri ( local storage file. ).
    private Uri audioFileUri = null;

    // Save web audio file url.
    private String audioFileUrl = "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4";

    // Check if stream audio.
    private boolean streamAudio = true;

    // Media player that play audio.
    private MediaPlayer audioPlayer = null;

    // Caller activity context, used when play local audio file.
    private Context context = null;

    // This Handler object is a reference to the caller activity's Handler.
    // In the caller activity's handler, it will update the audio play progress.
    private Handler audioProgressUpdateHandler;

    // This is the message signal that inform audio progress updater to update audio progress.
    public final int UPDATE_AUDIO_PROGRESS_BAR = 1;

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getAudioFileUrl() {
        return audioFileUrl;
    }

    public void setAudioFileUrl(String audioFileUrl) {
        this.audioFileUrl = audioFileUrl;
    }

    public boolean isStreamAudio() {
        return streamAudio;
    }

    public void setStreamAudio(boolean streamAudio) {
        this.streamAudio = streamAudio;
    }

    public Uri getAudioFileUri() {
        return audioFileUri;
    }

    public void setAudioFileUri(Uri audioFileUri) {
        this.audioFileUri = audioFileUri;
    }

    public Handler getAudioProgressUpdateHandler() {
        return audioProgressUpdateHandler;
    }

    public void setAudioProgressUpdateHandler(Handler audioProgressUpdateHandler) {
        this.audioProgressUpdateHandler = audioProgressUpdateHandler;
    }

    // Start play audio.
    public void startAudio()
    {
        initAudioPlayer();
        if(audioPlayer!=null) {
            audioPlayer.start();
//            ProgressUtils.dismissProgress();
        }
    }



    // Stop play audio.
    public void stopAudio()
    {
        if(audioPlayer!=null) {
            audioPlayer.stop();
            destroyAudioPlayer();
        }
    }

    // Initialise audio player.
    private void initAudioPlayer()
    {
        try {
            if (audioPlayer == null) {
                audioPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getAudioFileUrl())) {
                    if (isStreamAudio()) {
                        audioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    }
                    audioPlayer.setDataSource(getAudioFileUrl());
                } else {
                    audioPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), getAudioFileUri());
                }

                audioPlayer.prepare();


            }
        }catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Destroy audio player.
    private void destroyAudioPlayer()
    {
        if(audioPlayer!=null)
        {
            if(audioPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                audioPlayer.stop();
            }

            audioPlayer.release();

            audioPlayer = null;
        }
    }

}
```

I have to tried to implement online streaming radio application, but it is stop when screen lock after few minute please help me to fix this problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // User input mp3 file url in this text box. Or display user selected mp3 file name.
    private static String audioFileUrl = "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4";


    private AudioServiceBinder audioServiceBinder = null;

    private Handler audioProgressUpdateHandler = null;

    // Show played audio progress.
//    private ProgressBar backgroundAudioProgress;

    ImageView startBackgroundAudio;
    ImageView stopBackgroundAudio;


    // This service connection object is the bridge between activity and background service.
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
              iBander object.
            audioServiceBinder = (AudioServiceBinder) iBinder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {

        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        // Bind background audio service when activity is created.


        bindAudioService();

        // Click this button to start play audio in a background service.
        startBackgroundAudio = findViewById(R.id.start_audio_in_background);
        stopBackgroundAudio = findViewById(R.id.stop_audio_in_background);
        startBackgroundAudio.post(() -> {


            startBackgroundAudio.setOnClickListener(view -> {

                new PrograssAsyncTask(this).execute();


                startBackgroundAudio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                stopBackgroundAudio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                ProgressUtils.showProgress(MainActivity.this);
                // Set web audio file url
                audioServiceBinder.setAudioFileUrl(audioFileUrl);

                // Web audio is a stream audio.
                audioServiceBinder.setStreamAudio(true);

                // Set application context.
                audioServiceBinder.setContext(getApplicationContext());

                // Initialize audio progress bar updater Handler object.
//            createAudioProgressbarUpdater();
                audioServiceBinder.setAudioProgressUpdateHandler(audioProgressUpdateHandler);

                // Start audio in background service.
                audioServiceBinder.startAudio();

            });
        });


        stopBackgroundAudio.post(() -> {
            stopBackgroundAudio.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                startBackgroundAudio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                stopBackgroundAudio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                audioServiceBinder.stopAudio();
                abc.stopAudio();
            });
        });

//        ProgressUtils.showProgress(MainActivity.this);


        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(() -> {
            autoPlay();
        });



    }

    AudioServiceBinder abc;

    private void autoPlay() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.ServiceStopped");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        abc = new AudioServiceBinder();
        abc.setContext(getApplicationContext());
        abc.setAudioProgressUpdateHandler(audioProgressUpdateHandler);
        abc.startAudio();
    }

    // Bind background service with caller activity. Then this activity can use
    // background service's AudioServiceBinder instance to invoke related methods.
    private void bindAudioService() {
        if (audioServiceBinder == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AudioService.class);
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            @SuppressLint("InvalidWakeLockTag")
            PowerManager.WakeLock screenWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK  | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
                    "ScreenLock tag from AlarmListener");
            screenWakeLock.acquire();
            // Below code will invoke serviceConnection's onServiceConnected method.
            bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            screenWakeLock.release();

        }
    }

    // Unbound background audio service with caller activity.
    private void unBoundAudioService() {
        if (audioServiceBinder != null) {
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // Unbound background audio service when activity is destroyed.
        unBoundAudioService();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class PrograssAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public PrograssAsyncTask(MainActivity activity) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait......");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
            // do background work here
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // do UI work here
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
//        autoPlay();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have added service tag my manifests file als

Answer (score 1):

You can make your service a foreground service, which will display an icon in the notification bar so that the user can see your service is running.

**Otherwise, you cannot keep your service running.**

By the way, you should be aware that an everlasting service is an Android antipattern, the system should be able to kill off your app when memory is low, and apps haven't used it in a while.

If you are doing something that legitimately needs to live "forever" you should do so with a foreground service.

Read this for more information:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: Foreground service will also be killed by os. You need to acquire wake lock on cpu to keep service running.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but someone might find it helpful.

To prevent serviced being killed you need to acquire wakelock.

```
[Service]
internal class NotificationService : Service
{
    readonly PowerManager.WakeLock _wakeLock;

    public NotificationService()
    {
        PowerManager powerManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService) as PowerManager;
        _wakeLock = powerManager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "ServiceWakeLock");
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        _wakeLock?.Acquire();
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        _wakeLock?.Release();

        base.OnDestroy();
    }
}
```